# Как организовать общение пользователей в сети по средствам PTP соединения в Xamarin Forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, ptp

На данный момент общение между пользователями имеет следующий вид (клиент - сервер - клиент ) на сервере запущен "TCP-чат" если можно так выразится. Клиенты к нему подключаются и общаются , передавая информацию сначала серверу и только потом клиенту. Сервер имеет белый-ip, так что общаться можно откуда угодно.  Но большое количество клиентов здорово нагружают сервак. как для новичка и это далось не просто. Теперь хочется разобраться, можно ли как то настроить обмен информацией без основного сервера , что бы клиенты общались напрямую, естественно что бы найти друг друга , они изначально обменяются адресами друг друга , а дальше начнут общение между собой. [Вот статья](https://professorweb.ru/my/csharp/web/level8/8_3.php) , которую пришлось прочитать для малейшего понимая работы PTP, однако приведенный в конце статьи пример, работает только на Windows для Dekstop приложений. Мне нужна помощь, что бы понять как это работает и какими инструментами нужно пользоваться.

Comment: SignalR вам в помощь, с его хабами.

Comment: Как вариант, портируйте предолженную библиотеку на .NET Standard. Это не должно быть сложно. Исходники, вероятно, можно найти. А может уже и готовое что-то есть. Осталось только поискать.